# Anyone familiar with <center>?

Tags: html, tags

I see this in a website for the first time of life.

Is it supported by all browsers?

Comment: we are certainly living in a naive world

Comment: omg... you know you're getting old when the young whipper snappers haven't heard of these old deprecated tags.

Comment: There were also <marquee> and <blink> . Oh, those were the days...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's deprecated as of HTML 4.01 and not supported in XHTML 1.0. Major browsers will support it though.

Answer (score 3):

It's [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_center.asp). Use [CSS to center elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp). It is supported in all major browsers though...

Answer (score 3):

<center> is not part of the [HTML 4.01 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/), so it's likely that some browsers wouldn't understand it.

The more correct way to center text uses the [CSS text-align](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center) property.

If a browser doesn't understand a tag, it should ignore that tag.  So, even if a browser doesn't understand <center>, it should not ruin the web page.

Answer (score 0):

center tag puts the content in the middle of the line. It's kind of old-fashioned. CSS can do this well.